# r filter data frame with unique fields

Tags: r

I am giving the first steps with coding and with R and i have a problem:

I have one data frame with this format:

```
Months| Person

April Person1

May Person2

April Person1

June Person 3

May Person4
```

and i want this output:

```
May - Person2, Person4

April - Person1

June - Person3
```

I am using `unique(df$months)` and i get the unique months but i can't obtain the persons.

I was thinking save the index of each `unique(df$months)` and select the "person" of these index... this for each `unique(df$months)`. But this doesn't seems "optimal" or good practice.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `aggregate` (from `base R`) after removing the "duplicate" rows (`unique(df)`) and use (`toString`) to `paste` together the unique "Person" grouped by "Months".  `toString` is a wrapper for `paste(., collapse=', ')`

```
aggregate(.~Months, unique(df), toString)
#   Months           Person
#1  April          Person1
#2   June          Person3
#3    May Person2, Person4
```

Or the same can be done in  `data.table` by first converting to "data.table" (`setDT`),removing duplicates etc...

```
library(data.table)
 unique(setDT(df))[,list(Person=toString(Person)) , Months]
```

Comment: thanks it works... and much easier.... thanks :D

Comment: Wouldn't `aggregate(Person ~ Months, df, toString)` also work? `unique` seems like an overhead in this case. It also seems like this was asked so many times, and still can't find a good dupe..

Comment: @DavidArenburg  I tried that earlier, but it will have `April Person1, Person1`

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Are you getting different results?  I have both `character` columns.

Comment: I didn't try running it