# list unique values for each level within a column in R

Tags: r

I have a large data set of species (column 1) and associated character data (column 2). I want to create an output of all unique data values for each species. Here are some dummy data:

```
species<-c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C")
value<-c("x","x","y","x","y","z","z","z","z")
df<-data.frame(species,value)
df
```

species value
1       A     x
2       A     x
3       A     y
4       B     x
5       B     y
6       B     z
7       C     z
8       C     z
9       C     z

I first wanted to see counts for each value by species. To do this, I used table()
    with(df, table(species,value))
        value
species x y z
      A 2 1 0
      B 1 1 1
      C 0 0 3

Now, I would like to be able to list the different values for each species. For example, I am looking for something like this:

species unique.values
      A x,y
      B x,y,z
      C z

Ideas for the best way to do something like this?

Comment: A similar question was asked by somebody within half an hour. `aggregate(value~species, unique(df), toString)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27843998/r-filter-data-frame-with-unique-fields/27844065#27844065

Comment: Homework problems abound.